# Binding a BitmapImage object from a class inside a ListView with WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a problem with a WPF application.
I would like to bind a BitmapImage object which is inside a class into an Image object inside my XAML.
So I'm doing this way :
(I'm directly adding this class into the ListView) :

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Adress As String, ByVal ISAF As Boolean)
    IWorking = showIcon(sName.Substring(sName.LastIndexOf(".")))
    Dim IconMemStream As New MemoryStream
    IWorking.ToBitmap.Save(IconMemStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    sImage = New BitmapImage
    sImage.BeginInit()
    sImage.StreamSource = IconMemStream
    sImage.EndInit()
    IconMemStream.Close()
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Image"))
End Sub
```

And Inside the XAML I'm using this :

```
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="32" Height="32" />
                                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
```

The name shows but the bitmap not.
I checked if the sImage object had the bitmap, and it has.
But, the problem seems to be in the binding.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like what you are after: http://www.vbnettutorial.net/?Id=137&Desc=Wpf-Listbox-Image-Binding-From-Db